# How to make div expand in bootstrap instead of use scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and am using the class col-md-6. On the left column I have an image and on the right column I have two paragraphs of text. When I shrink the web browser (or use mobile), I want the div to expand, instead of using a scroll bar. What ends up happening now is the image shows up fine but I have to use the scroll bar to see the paragraphs of text.

Sorry I'm kind of new to web programming and have spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Not sure if it's relevant but I'm also including the next chunk of code after the issue.

I want it to scroll from pg4 to pg5, but i don't want an additional scrollbar to have to see all the content in pg4.

EDIT: Also feel like I should note that I've seen similar questions posted here and have tried numerous of the answers to these issues and nothing has worked yet.

```
<div id="pg4">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">About Me</h1><hr/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="IMAGE" class="center-block img-responsive" id="picture" alt="Picture" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1</p>
        <p>PARAGRAPH 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="pg5">
</div>

/* PG 4 */
#pg4 {
  background-color: #282E34;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 250%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#pg4 p {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  color: #6c6d6e;
}

#p1 {
  margin-top: 15%;
}

#picture {
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

/* PG 5 */
#pg5 {
  background-image: url("IMAGE");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: remove `height: 100%` from both `pg4` and `pg5`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add additional classes to your divs

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
    <img src="IMAGE" class="center-block img-responsive" id="picture" alt="Picture" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
    <p>PARAGRAPH 1</p>
    <p>PARAGRAPH 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Something like this.

If you do not specify `col-xs-?` by default bootstrap stacked your divs and it behaves like `col-xs-12`. Same for large displays. So you need to specify a width for extra small and large displays

And from that part:

```
#picture {
 width: 45%;
 margin-top: 15%;
}
```

remove `width: 45%` you already defined `img-responsive`

Answer (score 0):

When you set `height` and `overflow: auto` for an element, It means you want this element to be scrollable. If you don't want this, instead of `height: 100%` set `height: auto;`